# How do I pass variable value as bracket expansion sequence value?

Tags: bash, shell-script

The code block in particular is:

```
for n in {1..$PASSEDARGS}; do
      printf "%s\n" "$n"
done
```

The following code block doesn't work, instead it prints `{1..3}` where 3 is the value of the number of arguments passed to the script.

How do I make the program print the argument at `$n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the C-like for-loop syntax of Bash:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= PASSEDARGS; ++i )); do
  printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

Comment: I was thinking this approach, but I wanted to keep with the bracket expansion method. This one should suffice.

Comment: @guest_2019238121 I was uncertain whether you wanted the numbers or the values of the positional parameters. If you want the values of `$1`, `$2`, etc., then just iterate over `"$@"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for n in $(seq $#); do
      printf "%s\n" "$n"
      eval echo argument at $n: \$$n
done
```

Comment: Wow, eval of an echo of an unquoted, unsanitized, variable!  Try that with `set - "hello;ls"`.